# Count items in pipeline of lookup

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections: `parent` and `children`.

My parent collection is :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f0899303a766b020f0062aa"
    },
    "children": "aaa"
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f0899173a766b020f0062a8"
    },
    "children": "aaa"
}
```

My children collection is:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f0899d13a766b020f0062ab"
    },
    "uid": "aaa"
}
```

I try to find the number of `parent` items for each item in the `children` collection. The link is `children` in the `parent` collection and `uid` in the `children` collection.

I have an aggregation like this:

```
const agg = [
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'parent',
            "let": { "the_uid": "$uid" },
            'pipeline': [
                {
                    '$match':
                    {
                        '$expr':
                        {
                            '$eq': ["$$the_uid", "$children"]
                        }
                    }
                },
                { "$count": "count" }
            ],
            'as': 'parent_count'
        }
    },
    {
        '$limit': 5
    }
];
```

The result of this aggregation is :

```
{
  _id: 5f0899d13a766b020f0062ab,
  uid: 'aaa',
  parent_count: [ { count: 2 } ]
}
```

I would like to know how I could have a result more like this (so simplify the `parent_count` result):

```
{
  _id: 5f0899d13a766b020f0062ab,
  uid: 'aaa',
  parent_count: 2
}
```

Thank you for you answer.

Comment: Try adding a $project stage.

Comment: Ok, I added two $project in my pipeline:
`{ "$project": { "parent_count": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$parent_count", 0] } } },
{ "$project": { "parent_count": "$parent_count.count" } },` The result is good. Do you think there is a way to simplify? Thank you.

Comment: You could make that a single project stage like `{$project:{parent_count:{$arrayElemAt:["$parent_count.count",0]}}}`